# DIV's height automatic adjust

Tags: php, css, html

I'm using div's en css code, to get some values out of a mysql database.

It works fine. But if the value in the database is longer than 1 row, the table with div's doesn't look nice.

This is the code I'm using:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boxen ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo '<div class="a naam">';
    echo '<a href="boxen.php?boxid=' .  $row['ID'] . '">' . $row['naam'] . '</a>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="a datum">';
    echo $row['datum'];
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="a land">';
    echo $row['land'];
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="a naam">';
    echo $row['starter'];
    echo '</div>';
    }
```

The css code adjusts the color, and the width.
Short: how do I fix the height?

P.s. I have searched on stackoverflow, but found nothing that can help me, maybe I'm using the wrong keywords?

EDIT:

```
<div class="inhoud">
<h2>Inhoud van de box: </h2><br />
<div class="header naam">
    Naam product
</div>
<div class="header omschrijving">
    Omschrijving
</div>
<div class="header aantal">
    Aantal
</div>
<div class="header datum">
    Datum toegevoegd
</div>
<div class="header naam">
    Naam toeveoger
</div>
<div class="header datum">
    Datum verwijderd
    </div>
<div class="header naamVerwijderaar">
    Naam verwijdereraar
</div>
<div class="header icon">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="header icon">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="header icon">
    SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE
</div>
```

This is the header, but it has the same problem. The last column will have 2 rows, and if I add a another line, it gets very cluttered.

And the css code:

```
/* Algemeen voor header*/
.header {
    background-color:#4DA0FF;   
    float:left;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    color:white;

}
/* END HEADER*/
/* ALGEMEEN OVERIZCHT*/
/* naam */
.naam{
width:200px;
height:auto;
}
/* naam die het product er uit heeft gehaald*/
.naamVerwijderaar{
width:210px;
height:auto;

}
/* datum  */
.datum{
width:150px;
height:auto;

}


/* omschrijinvg */
.omschrijving{
    width:200px;
    height:auto;

}
.aantal {
    width:80px;
    height:auto;

}
/* land */
.land{
width:150px;
height:auto;

}
inhoud{
    width:1305px;
}
```

I don't need all the css code for this example!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Tnx! I know that I need to use that! I have found a good tutorial, and I will start learning it soon, but I need to fix this first. But I will use you advise!

Comment: Please show us the HTML that's being generated from your script, as well as the CSS code you use on it.

Comment: I have edit my question above. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is there a way to do this? I hope you undestand my question?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with it. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. This is a online example http://beta.ledfanselektronica.be/test.php I want that if the colum is heigher, because there is more text (like colom 2) that the hole row is heigher. Again, excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: Mmm, there is a way to do this in PHP, I think. I will do this with strlen. Thanks for the help so far on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a table for this sort of things.

Tables are not all evil, when used for the correct type of data (tabular data, i.e. the kind of data best fit in a table), tables are perfectly acceptable.

Sample code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    th {
        background-color: rgb(77, 160, 255);
        margin-left:      4px;
        margin-bottom:    4px;
        color:            rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    table caption {
        font-size:   2em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <caption>Inoud van de box:</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Naam product</th>
            <th>Omschrijving</th>
            <th>Antal</th>
            <th>Datum toegevoegd</th>
            <th>Naam toevegoer</th>
            <th>Datum verwijderd</th>
            <th>Naam verwijderd</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I agree with that one! You don't need every to be tableless, these are perfectly acceptable HTML elements and well structured.

Comment: @LEDfan: No problem. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the large green tick mark under this answer's vote count.

Comment: @LEDfan: You have enough reputation to accept an answer for a question you posted. Try it.